# PHP Deprecated: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding on StringLength.php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend 1.x. I am facing following PHP error.

> PHP Deprecated:  iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated in /cds/PVTS/usoc/library/Zend/Validate/StringLength.php on line 209

I have found some temporary fix for the issue. like as follows:

```
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 50600)
     iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', $orig);
else
     ini_set('default_charset', $encoding);
```

But this change I have to perform in each zend library file, which contains this piece of code.

Is there any permanent fix of this problem?

Comment: What php version are you using?

Comment: PHP Version - 5.6.8

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using ini_set in the code you could update the server's php.ini on the servers running the later versions of PHP.

Or if preferred use a .htaccess file - using something like

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
php_value default_charset UTF-8
```

You'll still get the deprecated warnings - but they can be suppressed from showing on the live environment. Ultimately looking to upgrade the version of Zend you're using may be the better (but no doubt may be less practical) long term solution.

Comment: If I upgrade to Zend 2.x, will this issue get resolved??

Comment: Zend 2 is a large rewrite and I've not encountered this deprecated warning using it. If this is an existing site you may find you have considerable work to do in order to make the site work under the new version of Zend though.